# Google Earth Plugin will not load under Windows 7 in Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: kml, virtualbox, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to load the Google Earth Plugin on Window 7 x64 guest operating system running under Oracle Virtual Box. I have tried to do this under the latest version of 3 different browsers (IE, Chrome, FF). The Plugin Window appears with the rotating GIF indicating GE is loading. It stop rotating and then (apparently) nothing..

However at that point GEPLUGIN goes to 100% CPU usage in task manager and starts consuming memory. After about 5 mins, memory gets up to around 200+K and then the GEPlugin reports "There was a problem with the Google Earth Plugin. Please Try reloading the page..

I have tried uninstall and re-installing multiple times under different browsers with no success. Outside of the VM this works perfectly, and I will swear it worked inside the VM about a year ago.

The VM is configured to allow 256M of Video memory, ^GB of System memory and enables 2D and 3d acceleration. If tried different combinations of 2D &3D enabled and disabled without luck..

Any ideas.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solved this issue? Followed http://www.innovatiway.com/joomla/index.php/79-it-articles/75-google-earth-plugin-problem-black-screen with no result..

Answer (score 0):

I still does not know why it not worked previously but now its is ok. It was about my enviroment.
Not worked on: `host ubuntu 12.04 lts_x64, virtualizing (vbox 4.1) x64 windows 7`

actually I made new machine and plugin works properly.
Works on: the same `host ubuntu 12.04 lts_x64, virtualizing (vbox 4.3) x64 windows 8.1.`

Firefox/chrome for both.